# Compare two lists in Ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Seems simple enough, but I'm very new to this language and having some trouble. Given two lists, what would be the best way to write a function to determine which list is "larger."

For example: [1:2:3] and [1:3:2] would return [1:3:2]

These lists don't have to be the same length: [1:2] and [1:2:3] would return [1:2:3]

Thanks.

Comment: Not much, somewhat lost on how to start. Gone through this: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html

Comment: OK then I'll give you a hint. Which one should be larger, `[1; 3]`, or `[1; 2; 3]`? If the latter, then you need to _first_ compare the _lengths_ of the lists, _then_ compare them element-wise. Also: it's OK to start with an incorrect implementation. In fact, you can post that here so people can help debug it.

Comment: OK, another hint: there are built-in functions to do both parts I mentioned above, in the documentation you linked to. For the first part, you probably know which function I mean. For the second part, look in the 'List scanning' section.

Comment: @Yawar, computing the length first is completely unnecessary and inefficient.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg but it is instructive.

Comment: @Yawar, abusing List.length is a very common beginner's mistake that you don't want to encourage. In this case, if the idea is to implement the function yourself then length is in fact just complicating it.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg ah, I see now. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

The predefined function `max` will do this for you:

```
# max [1;2;3] [1;3;2];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 2]
# max [1;2] [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

Of course, it depends on what you mean by "larger". The built-in comparisons of OCaml use [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). If you wanted to use some other order, you would actually have to write your own function.

Or maybe you want to write your own function from scratch just for the practice. In that case, a good way to go with lists in OCaml is to use recursion. Try out some patterns of recursion and (if you still need help), update your question to show what you've tried.